# Redirect traffic flowing into SSH server to privoxy, then to TOR

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

I own a Ubuntu VPS that I am using for SSH tunneling. I want the traffic to be redirected to TOR network. Some research showed that I can do it by using Privoxy, that will accept traffic from SSH tunnel and forward it to TOR. I know how to setup Privoxy but I don't know how to forward SSH traffic to Privoxy.

**What is working now:**

Local Client === SSH Tunnel ===> SSH server ===> Internet

Privoxy is listening at VPS `localhost:9090`. On my local PC, I use the following command to setup tunnel successfully:

> ssh -ND 5555 VPSuser@VPS

**What I want to work:**

Local Client === SSH Tunnel ===> SSH server ===> Privoxy ===> TOR ===> Internet

**What I have already tried:**

Following the instructions on [Redirect SSH traffic through Privoxy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065937), I tried using the following command on the client to open tunnel but Firefox keeps saying 'The connection is reset':

> ssh -L 5555:127.0.0.1:9090 VPSuser@VPS

I have very limited experience of networking in Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Come on people this is a very common scenario. I can't believe no one has ever faced it.